# How to automatically add page number for referenced figure/table if not in the immediate text vicinity

Tags: cross-referencing, page-numbering

I have realised as I write my thesis that at times I need to cite figures from completely different sections to discuss a point that is connected (some are figures in future sections some in past).

Is there a way to have LaTeX automatically cite the page after the figure number in parentheses ( ) if the figure is not in the immediate vicinity of where the reader is reading at this time? So if its in a different \section or \subsection?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the [varioref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package and its `\vref` macro?

Comment: I prefer to be in control and add `\ref` or `\ref` accompanied with `\pageref` as appropriate for the context.

Comment: You also can take a look at the  `cleveref` package, which supports and improves `varioref`, among many features.

Comment: Thank you I did not know of any of these, I will look into each one. I will let you know feedback on their results.

Comment: Is there any news here?